# Standalone Library to Connect to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql, ironpython

I've recently wrote up a little application for work to ease our on the fly notetaking. I wrote the program in IronPython, but have since hit a brickwall as I  can't find an easy way to connect to an external MySQL server we host for record keeping.

My constraints for this application are that it has to be purely portable across both Win XP and 7 systems. So basically, no installations.

I've read up on MySQLdb and some others but can't seem to find anything that does not require installation.

What classes or libraries can I use to straightforwardly connect to a MySQL server, without installing anything? If there are none for IronPython, is there one for another language? Alternatively, is there a way to use MySQLdb without requiring it to be installed on the client system?

Comment: the mysql client will happily read SQL from stdin. The mysql client bundle includes mysqlimport which handles CSV files (although I've problems with the latter).

Comment: Could you specify what you mean with "does not require installation"? Is your app a single `.py` file? What about using/including .NET assemblies (i.e. [MySQL connector for .NET](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.8.html) )?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, so essentially, I don't want my application to require any sort of installation to run. Just a simple double click and away the user goes.

Some further background, I'm developing it in SharpDevelop (portable edition) which creates an executable file for users to run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A very simple and easy to deploy solution is using [Connector/Net](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/).
You only depend on a single assembly (`mysql.data.dll`) that needs to reside beside your application (or wherever you choose).
[The documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-sql-command.html) has a few examples on how to use the connector from C#/.NET which can be used as a guide on how to use it from IronPython as well.

Another possible solution could be using [Connector/Python](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/python/). It is native python without any managed or native assemblies but it comes in the form of several `.py` files which could possibly be embedded within your executable.

`MySQLdb` probably won't work because of its native assemblies.

Comment: Thanks Simon, this has worked for me. :)